# Do independent rules influence one another?

Tags: antlr

When I was debugging my grammar for C# I noticed something very unusual: some inputs that are not accepted by a full grammar are being accepted by the same grammar with some independent rules deleted. I could not find a logical explanation. For example:

[CS](http://pastebin.com/dZ27GA7J) - this grammar does not accept the input `a<a<a>><EOF>`

[CS'](http://pastebin.com/fDn2d35i) - and this grammar which is basically the same as [CS](http://pastebin.com/dZ27GA7J) but with some independent rules deleted (rules are not reordered) does accept `a<a<a>><EOF>`

As you can see both grammars start with the rule `start: namespaceOrTypeName EOF;` and therefore they should call the same set of  rules ([CS](http://pastebin.com/dZ27GA7J) will never call those rules that are deleted in [CS'](http://pastebin.com/fDn2d35i)). I spent a day debugging this, deleting or adding new rules, but couldn't find a flaw in the logic. Any help would be of use, thank you.

[Unicode](http://pastebin.com/dEePy1Y6)

EDIT:
After changing the start rule in [CS](http://pastebin.com/dZ27GA7J) to `start: Identifier EOF;` the grammar starts rejecting the input `method` which is normally accepted when only `Identifier` rules are defined. So I guess, since there is a rule `attributeTarget: ...| 'method' | ...`, that after compiling the grammar some phrases get reserved such as 'method' in this case but I'm not still sure if thats the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first grammar includes the `overloadableBinaryOperator` rule which implicitly defines the `>>` token. Since `>>` is a 2-character token, the lexer will never treat the input `>>` as two separate 1-character tokens `>`, `>`. If you open the grammar in ANTLRWorks 2, you'll see a warning indicator for each implicitly-defined token. You should remove all of these warnings by:

1. Creating explicit lexer rules for every token you intend to appear in the input.
2. Only using the syntax `'new'` in a parser rule if a corresponding lexer rule exists for the literal `'new'`.